# value of the variable @@rowcount

Tags: sql, sql-server, scope, rowcount

having the following sql script:

```
declare @table table(id int)

insert into @table values (1),(2)

--print @@rowcount

if 3 < 2 
    print 'false'

--print @@rowcount
```

if I'm uncommenting the first print, it will print he value 2, but if I am uncommenting the last print, it will print 0. So the instruction `IF` is affecting the value of the variable `@@ROWCOUNT`? Or what is the scope of this variable?

I am using sql server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Global variable [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will return the number of rows affected by the last statement. Run after the INSERT statement, it will return 2 (rows). Run after the IF statement, it will return the number of rows affected by the IF statement, which is zero.

This also means in the SQL below the 2 @@rowcount statements return 2 then 0 (zero) as the first @@rowcount statement affects zero rows

```
declare @table table(id int)
insert into @table values (1),(2)
print @@rowcount
print @@rowcount
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  `@@ROWCOUNT` refers to the previous statement and it is constantly being reassigned.  This is why it is usually used for assignment to a variable:

```
declare @rowcnt int;

<whatever>

set @rowcnt = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql) gives examples of how it works in some situations, but doesn't list `IF` specifically.

However, with a bit of testing, it appears that an `IF` statement *that was not executed* resets it to `0`. This makes sense if you think of `IF` as a statement that wraps the statement/block inside it:

- if the condition was true, the `IF` statement affected however many rows the statement inside affected
- if the condition was not true, and there is an `ELSE` block, it affected however many rows the statement inside that affected
- if the condition was not true, and there is no `ELSE` it affects zero rows

Compare:

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE(id INT)

INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES (1),(2),(3)

IF 1 = 2
    SELECT * FROM @TEST
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT
-- 0, because block didn't run

IF 1 = 1
    SELECT * FROM @TEST
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT
-- 3, i.e. number of rows in SELECT

IF 1 = 2 
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @TEST
ELSE
    SELECT TOP 2 * FROM @TEST
PRINT @@ROWCOUNT
-- 2, i.e. number of rows in the SELECT executed in the ELSE clause
```